# flex-wrap and spacing/margins

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to put some panels on my site but whanever I add a new panel there is a giant spacing between the panels, which won't go away.. only if I add more panels than it will eventually smooth out.

How can I get rid of this?

**Screenshot**

[image: CLICK HERE]

```css
.page-case {
  width: 375px;
  height: 225px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.page-content-inner {
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: calc(100% - 65px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content-inner">
  <div class="page-case">

  </div>
  <div class="page-case">

  </div>
  <div class="page-case">

  </div>
  <div class="page-case">

  </div>
  <div class="page-case">

  </div>
</div>
```

**Solved** I set a height which makes the distance between the rows expand.

Comment: are you sure you included all of your css to reproduce the problem? I'm using chrome and I don't see it.

Comment: @MichaelCoker weird, it doesn't happen on jsfiddle either..

Comment: It was because I had set a height